# Panel collapse icon is not displayed properly

Tags: bootsfaces

As you can see below, the icon (in the right corner) is not displayed properly.
Usually, it is an arrow down, as you can see in the [showcase](http://bootsfaces.net/layout/panels.jsf) of BootsFaces.

[image: Panel]

My `<b:panel>` looks like:

```
<b:panel title="Beiträge (1)" collapsible="true"look="info">
```

How can I display the correct icon?

I am not using any specific theme and I am using BootsFaces 0.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had a lot of trouble with this. Most likelely the Glyphicons rource file can't be loaded.

1. Make sure you've added a `<h:head></h:head>` tag (even if it's empty). Do not use the HTML tag (`<head />`).
2. Check the URL pattern of the web.xml. Many tutorials recommend to put the JSF files into a virtual folder, such as `<url-pattern>/pages/</url-pattern>` . Don't do that. There's nothing wrong with simple patterns like `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>`. By the way, this is the default, so you can safely omit the url-pattern altogether.
3. If that fails, add the `CombinedResourceHandler` of OmniFaces. This always does the trick for me.
4. Check the URL in your browser. Maybe you entered `localhost:8080/index.xhtml` instead of `localhost:8080/index.jsf`?
5. If you're still stuck, open an issue on the BootsFaces GitHub repository (https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues). But first read https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/157 - your problem is probably already fixed there.

Comment: 3. did the trick. But why? What is this? Also I found out, that the `glyhpicon` files were not loaded.

Comment: @alexander I'd like to know, too, but somehow I can't wrap my head around it. Do you have some spare time to investigate the topic? Just asking :).